# Suddenly stop working elastic search, Error message : Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch

I am stuck on this issue my code suddenly stops working not able to find the root cause of any idea regarding this. Earlier it was working fine. Kindly help. I have checked the all configuration are correct.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException: Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down? in /data/docroot/magento/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /data/docroot/magento/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Request.php(171): Elastica\Transport\Http->exec(Object(Elastica\Request), Array)
#1 /data/docroot/magento/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(662): Elastica\Request->send()
#2 /data/docroot/magento/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Search.php(461): Elastica\Client->request('elasticdata/...', 'GET', Array, Array)
#3 /data/docroot/magento/fetch_all_data.php(142): Elastica\Search->search(Object(Elastica\Query))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /data/docroot/magento/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php on line 186
```

Comment: you can try again install ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds most likely that Elasticsearch isn't running properly

If you run the following you should be able to determine if Elasticsearch is up.

curl localhost:9200

If you get a response with the Elasticsearch version etc, it is running. If it's not running, you'll need to check the Elasticsearch logs, normally found somewhere like /var/log/elasticsearch/